# Action Performed on both button java

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying one code but its not working properly
when I click on button register / login it will still system.out.println("cd");
so how do I like action perform on single button?
like when I click on button A it will appear the same text on all button but I want like if I will actionperform on button A then will show up like hello and when on B then bye

```
package com.delfrigon.learn2;



import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main implements ActionListener {




    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // Register & Login
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Login | Register");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        fr.add(panel);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setResizable(true);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setSize(700, 900);
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(".//libs//motorku.jpg");
        fr.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        panel.setLayout(null);


        JLabel usn = new JLabel("Username");
        usn.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(usn);
        JTextField txtfield = new JTextField(20);
        txtfield.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(txtfield);
        JLabel pwd = new JLabel("Password");
        pwd.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 25);
        panel.add(pwd);
        JPasswordField pwdfield = new JPasswordField(20);
        pwdfield.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(pwdfield);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Login");
        btn.setBounds(10, 80, 100, 25);
        btn.addActionListener(new Main());
        panel.add(btn);
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Register");
        btn2.setBounds(140, 80, 100, 25);
        btn2.addActionListener(new Main());
        panel.add(btn2);
        JLabel success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);
        fr.setVisible(true);


        // MySQL Connection
        Connection conn = null;
        String dbServer = "mysql-34517-0.cloudclusters.net"; // change it to your database server name
        int dbPort = 34560; // change it to your database server port
        String dbName = "usernamepasswords";
        String userName = "admin";
        String password = "sadsadsad";
        String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d?user=%s&password=%s",
                dbServer, dbPort, userName, password);
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected!");

        } catch (Exception e ){
            System.out.println("Check your login");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent btn2) {
        System.out.println("cd");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a java program. Why do you have the javascript tag? The two languages are very different.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to not to have a single class doing all the things. In this particular case, lamda expressions are a nice fit. So

```
public class Main implements ActionListener {
    // ...
    btn.addActionListener(new Main());
    // ...
    btn2.addActionListener(new Main());
```

becomes

```
public class Main {
    // ...
    btn.addActionListener(() -> {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    });
    // ...
    btn2.addActionListener(() -> {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    });
```

Also, almost everything using Swing should be done on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread as Swing is unfortunately *thread-hostile*. This is easy to achieve with method references (so long as you aren't throwing any checked exceptions).

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(Main::go);
}
private static void go() {
```

Answer (score 0):

At present you have only one ActionListener (your main method). You would need to setup different ActionListeners (classes implementing the interface). Attach the listeners to the buttons like you did here

```
btn.addActionListener(....)
...
btn2.addActionListener(....)
```

Having this separate listeners in place allows you to define different application login, i.e. on button A printing "Hello" and on button B printing "Bye".